# User logout session using Core data in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, core-data, logout

I am new to swift and trying to figure out things. I have created a user login/register using Core Data. How can I achieve the logout feature for the logged in user? I have been trying to find out how to save/destroy the state using core data, but couldn't find any useful information.

I tried creating a segue through the logout button, it changes the view controller but does not logout the user.